# [Android]Determine the transmit power of a wifi tethered device without rooting the phone

Tags: android, wifi, transmission, iwconfig

I need to determine the transmit power value of a a tethered wifi network in ad-hoc mode.

The current wifi tether applications in Android are mainly using **iwconfig** to configure the tethering which is an unofficial API.

Using this API it is possible to get the transmit power, as well as configure the tethered wife network using **iwconfig**.

However, it needs the phone to be rooted, and this does not work on every phone.

Since I am not interested in developing the wifi tether application, all I need is just the ability to check the transmit power if a device is already tethered. So, I don`t care if this value is given by the manufacturer or achieved programmatic.

Does anybody know of a way to do this without having the phone rooted?

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be a very old post. Hope the poster found their answer.

My search is somewhat related, and this post came up. What I am looking for is either software, an app, or a hardware device/meter from which I can read the output power of a WiFi device as well as check vswr of external antenna. I have an in-line meter that will do this for my CB radio but it only operates within a narrow band which WiFi is well outside of.

Anyway, sadly, I find it rare that a manufacturer posts output power. Alfa is one of the few that occasionally do. for example the AWUS036NHR. You will have to scroll down a little and choose "SPECIFICATIONS" They list Output Power and Sensitivity. Though this information was not readily available for several other products I looked at on their page.

https://www.alfa.com.tw/products/awus036nhr?_pos=1&_sid=89b94824e&_ss=r&variant=36477538271304

Also I found This link to have easily understandable info on conversions.

https://www.digitalairwireless.com/articles/blog/wifi-transmit-power-calculations-made-simples

Hope something here helps.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31992188)